# Libgdx Array of Rectangles

Tags: java, arraylist, rectangles

I am doing collision detection, and I need an array of rectangles to loop through. It is not working and instead gives me a null pointer exception.
This is my code:

```
Array<Rectangle> rects = new Array();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rects.add(rect);
```

Comment: How do you define and initialize rect?  Can you post a more complete code snippet?

Comment: i just make a new rectangle

Comment: Which line is giving you the null pointer error then?

Comment: Can you give us more code?

Comment: Im getting a null when i add rect.

Comment: why do you need more code?

Comment: Please attach code piece where you are creating `rect`

Comment: fixed it sorry.

Comment: Are you missing parenthesis? Try new Rectangle(); instead of new Rectangle;

Comment: sorry i do have that in my code just did not add it here

Comment: Check your syntax. Is it even correct?

Comment: i don't see why i could get a nullponter i very shere i have the syntax right

Comment: Can you please provide the full Stacktrace please. Otherwise it is not possible to give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
Array<Rectangle> rects = new Array();
```

to

```
Array<Rectangle> rects = new Array<Rectangle>();
```

Also, why use `Array` instead of `ArrayList`?